# Weblogic 10.3.6 error Unable to access the selected application

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, weblogic

i have a JSF2 / Hibernate web Application that works fine on netbeans8.2 using  Apache Tomcat 8.0.27.0 , when i try to deploy the war file on Weblogic server 10.3.6  it shows the Following error :

> - Error Unable to access the selected application.
> - Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
> - Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
> - Error Unmarshaller failed

i think there are missing files for weblogic server ? any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your log file for details

Comment: Did you get to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Exception in AppMerge flows - Issue will come with your weblogic server infrastructure. please verify the datasources.. etc.